# Serialization compatibility from Java 7 to Java 8

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

If an object is serialized in Java 7 then passed to a application running Java 8 with the same version of the Object (serialization value not explicitly set), should the Java 8 version be able to deserialize the object successfully? Is backward compatibility guaranteed (or guaranteed to fail)?

Comment: older but should still apply. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152757/is-java-object-serialization-compatible-between-1-5-and-1-6 (=should work in most cases)

Comment: most probably yes. see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html

Comment: It is guaranteed except for Swing objects where it is explicitly not.